# TTS in C++ Got an error when I was trying to use a string variable

Tags: c++, windows, text-to-speech, sapi

I created a void named "bot" to get text and speak it using a variable named "text". Like this,
`void bot(string text)`.
To use this void `bot("Hello")` or `bot("Hi, my name is blah blah")`
but it is not working.

Here is my code,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sapi.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void bot(string text)
{
    ISpVoice* pVoice = NULL;
    if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void**)&pVoice);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pVoice->Speak(text, 0, NULL);
        pVoice->Release();
        pVoice = NULL;
    }
    ::CoUninitialize();
}

int main()
{
    bot("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Any help please....

I tried like this,

```
    {
        hr = pVoice->Speak(L + text, 0, NULL);
        pVoice->Release();
        pVoice = NULL;
    }
```

And this,

```
    string sentence = text;
    {
        hr = pVoice->Speak(sentence, 0, NULL);
        pVoice->Release();
        pVoice = NULL;
    }
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: How about `pVoice->Speak(text.c_str(), 0, NULL);`?

Comment: Not working ***how***? What happens? What is supposed to happen? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: `Speak` wants a wide "C string", so use `std::wstring` and its `c_str`. (But please be more specific than "it is not working" and "it didn't work".)

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
int main()
{
    bot(L"Hello"); // L for wide string
    return 0;
}
```

and this

```
void bot(wstring text) // wide string
{
    ...
}
```

and this

```
hr = pVoice->Speak(text.c_str(), 0, NULL); // c_str() for C string
```

`Speak` apparently requires a wide C string. `wstring` is the type for a wide C++ string.  `c_str()` is the way you 'translate' from C++ strings to C strings. `L"hello"` is the way you write a wide string literal.